# Spécific Array initialisation

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

Is there a shorter way to do this ? :

```
$array = array(10,25,50,100,250,500,1000);

$associative = array_combine($array,$array);
```

So it could be associative by preference.
Something like :

`$associative = arraymagic(array(10,25,50,100,250,500,1000));`

and so the result could be

```
array (size=7)
  10 => int 10
  25 => int 25
  50 => int 50
  100 => int 100
  250 => int 250
  500 => int 500
  1000 => int 1000
```

Comment: shorter ? it's only 2 lines... but... why would you want to combine the same value in both keys and values ?

Comment: Just to initiate a select dropdown. For lisibility..

Comment: @Kwaadpepper - What do you mean with shorter? You only have two lines? Only shorter I can think of would be to set the keys from the beginning `$array = array(10=>10, 25=>25, 50=>50, 100=>100, 250=>250, 500=>500, 1000=>1000);`

Comment: Sorry i should be more specific, I meant something like
```$associative = arraymagic(array(10,25,50,100,250,500,1000));```

Comment: @Kwaadpepper- What? I don't understand at all? What is `arraymagic`? Edit your question and give an example of the result you would like to get.

Comment: @Kwaadpepper - Like I said in my previous comment, you get the desired result if you set the keys from the beginning.

Comment: if both keys and values are the same - why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of PHP 5.5 there is no explicit syntax for this.

Of course you can make it "shorter":

```
$a = [10,25,50,100,250,500,1000];
$a = array_combine($a,$a);
```

But this doesn't serve any purpose.

Update: why not implement your suggested `arraymagic` function yourself if you need this often?

```
function arraymagic($array)
{
    return array_combine($array, $array);
}
```

Comment: Of course, i was just wondering and of course i already checked the php doc, I just wanted to hear from someone else.

Comment: this only renames the variables and uses another way of declaring variables. It's not a true shorter way.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira yes. That was my point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$array = array(10,25,50,100,250,500,1000);` and as you comment you need it to `initiate dropdown` then why do you need both keys and values? Use just values:

```
foreach ($array as $v)
    echo '<option value="' . $v . '">' . $v . '</option>';
```

Or if you need keys, so as later assign something to them:

```
$array = array(10 => 1,25 => 1 , ...); // etc
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $k . '</option>';
```

Comment: I know like you many ways of doing this, i was just wondering if there was a function that already exists.